# How to Enable CORS for Apache httpd server? (Step-By-Step Process)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, cors

I was wondering if anybody can help me set up ***CORS*** on my Apache web server. I would appreciate a step-by-step process because many sites online are telling me different things. Like what do I need to do on my `httpd.conf` or `ssl.conf` files, where to put my `.htaccess` file, etc.

Answer (score 9):

The above answer is correct and put Inside the `httpd.conf`. This should be changed to whatever you set ***Document Root***.

On ***Ubuntu***, `httpd.conf` is located in the directory ***/etc/apache2***. `apache2.conf` is also located in ***/etc/apache2***.

On ***CENTOS 6*** `httpd.conf` in the path ***/etc/httpd/conf/httpd***.

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 8):

```
# edit your conf/httpd.conf file.  Verify that the headers module is loaded
LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so

# to whitelist every origin, use
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

More info: http://enable-cors.org/server_apache.html

Comment: Where do I put the `Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"` in?\

Comment: You can put everything in the same file.  It just needs to be placed somewhere after loading the module.  I think .htaccess would be fine as well (if they are enabled, with override permissions).

Comment: If I do add it to the .htaccess file, do I need to do something to the httpd.conf file where it allows .htaccess to be seen?

Comment: Yes, in that case you'd also need to set `AllowOverride FileInfo`  for that directory.  AllowOverride is valid only in <Directory> sections specified without regular expressions, not in <Location>, <DirectoryMatch> or <Files> sections.  More info:   http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html

Comment: I just put the .htaccess file in my /var/www directory. Is that OK?

Comment: .htacess will go at the base of wherever you are serving your webpages from.  For example, right next to the index.html of your website, for example.

Comment: Also, where do I put `AllowOverride FileInfo` in the httpd.conf? There are many places that I can put it at.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88215/discussion-between-user3851283-and-kevin-seifert).

Comment: Somewhere you should see the path to the base of your webpage's folder.  For example <Directory /var/www> ... </Directory>.  It goes inside that stanza.  If an `AllowOverride` already exists, just add the flag `FileInfo ` to it (separated by spaces).    If you see `AllowOverride none`, remove the `none` and replace it with `FileInfo`

Comment: However, there are multiple places that it has <Directory /var/www>. Do I just add `FileInfo` to the place that has my project directory in it?

Comment: Yes, that would be the best place...just to keep all the config for a site in one place

Comment: So I placed the Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" right below the project location directory. Is that OK?

Comment: yes.  then if you restart apache, you should see the header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"` show   up in all your reponses.   (you can verify with Chrome network tools)