# How to Enable CORS for Docker Apache httpd server?

Tags: apache, docker, cors, httpd.conf

I need to create an apache server to host my files and to get them by ajax. So, I'm using docker to deploy my server.

My docker image is httpd:2.4.

I deployed the server with the following command :

```
docker run -p 80:80 -dit --name file-server \
  -v /sources/docker/apache-server/www/:/usr/local/apache2/htdocs/ httpd:2.4
```

But when I want to make the request for ajax, this is the result:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://server/kml/example.kml. No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

So, I want to follow the next steps [How to Enable CORS for Apache httpd server? (Step-By-Step Process)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32273606/how-to-enable-cors-for-apache-httpd-server-step-by-step-process). But I do not know how to add that command in the httpd.conf of the component. And I don't have the httpd.conf template to replace it with:

```
v /sources/docker/apache-server/my-httpd.conf:/usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf
```

Please help me with this question.

Comment: Go inside the container and grab the default `httpd.conf`. Then modify as per your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You have that enter in shell-terminal with command `docker exec -it nameContainer sh` . write in terminal: **su** with those commands now you are root user in your Docker.

Now in terminal, you have than write `a2enmod headers` and restart your docker

The last command was for activate mod_header and just now you have that create a **.htaccess** in your project root file and write inside:

```
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

With that for me work fine and didn't need install apache in my machine

Answer (score -1):

This has certainly already been addressed elsewhere and has many different solutions, however it's the first search hit for 'cors apache docker' so here's my 2 cents:

The best solution (because it is *auditable* and *repeatable*) is to use the apache docker image as a base for your own image using the `docker build` command and a `Dockerfile`. I won't go in to that as that's not the direct question here, but the basic bits are the same.

Create an "extra" apache config file with the CORS header bits:

```
me@mymachine:~$ docker exec file-server bash -c 'printf "<Directory \"/var/www/html\">\n        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin \"*\"\n</Directory>\n" >> /usr/local/apache2/conf/extra/cors.conf'

me@mymachine:~$ docker exec file-server bash -c 'tail /usr/local/apache2/conf/extra/cors.conf'
<Directory "/var/www/html">
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</Directory>
```

Restart apache to use this new config:

```
me@mymachine:~$ docker exec file-server bash -c 'apachectl -k restart'
```

NOTE: If you haven't configured a `ServerName` anywhere, then you might see this warning which is unrelated to the CORS configuration:
`AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.17.0.3. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message`